# Como utilizar helpers no node.js para carregar configurações?

Tags: node.js

No **Laravel Framework** temos os arquivos de configuração centralizados no diretório `/config`, sendo que estes são simples arquivos **php** que retornam um *array* chave e valor.

Para acessar essas configurações em qualquer local da aplicação podemos utilizar o Helper `config`, logo, ao utilizar `config('app.timezone');` podemos acessar o conteúdo de /config/app.php, chave `timezone` e retornar o valor desta.

Como poderia ter um comportamento parecido no nodejs, preferencialmente utilizando um Helper tão simples como o citado acima?

Obs: caso seja relevante, estou utilizando Express.js no projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Você criar um arquivo de configuração **.js**, este arquivo contendo `module.exports` dos dados que você pretende utilizar. Como por exemplo assim:

**app.config.js**

```
module.exports = 
{
    webPort: 80,
    database:
    {
         url : "mongodb://localhost/app",
         user : "admin",
         password : "1234"
    }
}
```

De preferência este arquivo estará no root do projeto. Para acessar ele, é apenas dar um `require`:

```
const config = require("./app.config.js") //Considerando esteja no mesmo diretório.
```

Comment: Saberia me indicar um autoloader que me permita fazer “require” dinamicamente? Gostaria de importar no root algo que ao ser chamado invoque o arquivo correspondente, exemplo: `config(‘app.port')`. Em resumo, a função iria considerar `app` como arquivo e `port` como chave, para o exemplo anterior.